# Import shapefiles into database and access this data in ArcGIS Online

Tags: database, web-applications, arcgis, shapefile

I created a web app builder application and my data (shapefile data) is stored in the ArcGIS Online portal.But,I want to store my shapefiles data in database and access this data in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder application.

So please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to store the data in your own database, here's how:

1. Install ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Enterprise (Portal)
2. In ArcGIS Server, [register your database](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/manage-data/windows/registering-your-data-with-arcgis-server-using-manager.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_9D5CE649771049C6A0886A79E3C5B8AC). ([Postgres](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/manage-data/windows/register-postgresql-with-arcgis-server.htm), [SQL Server](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/manage-data/windows/register-sql-server-with-arcgis-server.htm))
3. In ArcGIS Pro, open the Database Connection and drag your table to data into the map.
4. [Share a web feature layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/web-feature-layer.htm), being sure to check check "Reference registered data"

Comment: You're welcome @ShalineeMishra - if this is the correct answer, please mark as "answer"